# Put the System.Windows.Form.ComboBox in Datagridview & operate by keyboard

Tags: c#, datagridview

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex==0)
    {

        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
        comboBox1.Visible = true;
        comboBox1.Location = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Location;
        comboBox1.Size = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.Size;

        comboBox1.Focus();
    }
}
```

in above code combobox dropdown property is not working

Comment: What do you mean by _not working_? You get any exception or error message?

Comment: no error, combobox dropdown is not expand

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583829/put-the-system-windows-form-combobox-in-datagridview-operate-by-keyboard) this link contain full code i have written

Answer (score 0):

You can set a new "Combobox row" with the following Code:

**CODE**

```
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chk = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(chk);
        chk.HeaderText = "Check Data";
        chk.Name = "chk";
        dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = true;
```

I hope this solves your problem! Have a nice day.

Comment: i want to put Combobox not CheckBox